# Yii2, find users that has active post

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-model

I have `user` and `post` table with `oneToMany` relation:

In Post Model:

```
public function getUser() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

And in User Model:

```
public function getPosts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

I want find All users that has at least a active post.
But I don`t have any idea.

My target SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM `user`
where id in (select user_id from post where status = 1)
```

What do I do?

```
User::find()->where(...
```

notice: its important that created with find(), because I want use it in search model

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add a condition using where.

It is recommend that(It query speed is faster than other):

```
$condition = <<<EOL
EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 from post t2 
       WHERE (t1.id = t2.user_id) 
              AND (t2.status = 1)
)
EOL;

User::find()->from(['t1'=>User::getTableSchema()->name])
    ->where(new yii\db\Expression($condition))
    ->all();
```

Comment: The ActiveQuery::alias method can be used instead of the `from(['t1'=>User::getTableSchema()->name])` ==>>  `User::find()->alias('t')`

Comment: @ingenious Thank you for your complement :).

Answer (score 1):

Best way:

```
User::find()->joinWith(['posts' => function(ActiveQuery $q){
    $q->where(['status' => 1]);
}])->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use literal where  however using User::find()

```
 User::find()->where('id in (select user_id from post where status = 1)');
```